# Fibonacci numbers in nature(Give examples)

Tags: soft-question, fibonacci-numbers

I heared a lot of things about fibonacci numbers in nature my friend says that there are about $300$ ways to find fibonacci numbers in nature but when I searched I can see just the sun flower and the tree where are the $300$? can you give other examples?

Comment: Im sure $300$ is just an arbitrary estimate. Pinecones come to mind. http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emat6680/parveen/fib_nature.htm

Comment: There are more than 300 sunflowers...

Comment: The number might not be $300$. Careful analysis may bring it down to $0$.